# .NET XSD validation confusion

Tags: c#, xml, validation, exception

I am attempting to use an `XmlReader` and associated `XmlReaderSettings` object to perform [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) validation on some documents. I am declaring a `ValidationEventHandler` which I was expecting would get called whenever the reader encounters a validation problem. However I am getting an `XSDValidationException` when I attempt to create the reader.

Any idea what would cause the exception? The message is:

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:base' attribute is not declared.

Could there be an issue with one of the underlying schemas?

Comment: What's the entire exception (`ex.ToString()`)? It may tell you the line number and position, and maybe even the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your actual XML document does not have a root element in no namespace.

This error can appear when your schema validation has a target namespace but the XML document being validated contains any root elements without a namespace.

Unfortunately schema validation in this case will only generate a warning that it does not find a matching schema for the root element and that warning is only displayed when a certain flag to report warnings is set, which is not set when using the Validate method of XmlDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Search your schemas and your document for an `xml:base` attribute. If present, then the schema defining that attribute will need to be in your schema set.

Answer (score 0):

A code sample would have been nice to be sure of what you're doing, but I can make some assumptions because I'm in the same spot. I came across [Using XSDs with includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128573/using-xsds-with-includes) and adapted the accepted answer to work for me.

The problem is that the `XmlReader` doesn't seem to know what the base path is for the included schema if you don't specify it while `Create()`ing the `XmlReader`. Assuming that you have a file path to your XML file, use `XmlReader.Create(Stream input, XmlReaderSettings settings, String baseUri)` and supply the path to the XML file as `baseUri`.

Example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

public void LoadXml(string path) {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlReader docReader;

    XmlReaderSettings rdrOpts = new XmlReaderSettings();
    rdrOpts.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    rdrOpts.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

    try {
        // This line is what you're looking for:
        docReader = XmlReader.Create(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), rdrOpts, Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        doc.Load(docReader);
    } catch (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException ex) {
        //...
    } //and catch any other relevant exceptions here, like System.IO.FileNotFoundException
}
```